# How to copy all the files of a particular type using Perl?

Tags: perl, file, copy

Right now, I am using something like

```
copy catfile($PATH1, "instructions.txt"), catfile($ENV{'DIRWORK'});
```

individually for each of the `.txt` files that I want to copy. This code is portable as it does not use any OS specific commands.

How can I copy **all** the text files from `$PATH1` to `DIRWORK`, when I do not know the individual names of all the files, while keeping the code portable?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "use File::Copy;" in the beginning of the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the core [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module like this:

```
use File::Copy;
my @files = glob("$PATH1/*.txt");

for my $file (@files) {
    copy($file, $ENV{DIRWORK}) or die "Copy failed: $!";
}
```

Comment: `<$PATH1/*.txt>` also is a glob ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using core [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/lib/File/Find.pm) and [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/lib/File/Copy.pm) and assuming you want all `.txt` files in `$PATH1` copied to `$ENV{DIRWORK}`, and *also* assuming you want it to recurse...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

die "ENV variable DIRWORK isn't set\n"
    unless defined $ENV{DIRWORK} and length $ENV{DIRWORK};
die "DIRWORK $ENV{DIRWORK} is not a directory\n"
    unless -d $ENV{DIRWORK};

my $PATH1 = q{/path/to/wherever};
die "PATH1 is not a directory" unless -d $PATH1;

find( sub{
    # $_ is just the filename, "test.txt"
    # $File::Find::name is the full "/path/to/the/file/test.txt".
    return if $_ !~ /\.txt$/i;
    my $dest = "$ENV{DIRWORK}/$_";
    copy( $File::Find::name, $dest ) or do {
        warn "Could not copy $File::Find::name, skipping\n";
        return;
    }
}, $PATH1 );
```

Give it a go ;)

Alternatively, why don't you use `bash` ?

```
$ ( find $PATH1 -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs -I{} cp {} $DIRWORK );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed to work on a Unix system (e.g. don't care about portability), I'll go against my own usual inclinations and accepted best practices and recommend considering using "cp" :)

```
system("cp $PATH1/*.txt $ENV{'DIRWORK'}"); 
# Add error checking and STDERR redirection!
```

For Perl native solution, combine globbed file list (or File::Find) with [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html#METHODS) ability to find actual file name

```
my @files = glob("$PATH1/*.txt");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my ($volume,$directories,$filename) = File::Spec->splitpath( $file );
    copy($file, File::Spec->catfile( $ENV{'DIRWORK'}, $filename ) || die "$!";
}
```

Comment: cannot use `cp` for the reason that you mentioned - portability.

Answer (score 0):

File::Find and File::Copy are portable:

```
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

find(
    sub {
        return unless ( -f $_ );
        $_ =~ /\.txt$/ && copy( $File::Find::name, $ENV{'DIRWORK'} );
    },
    $PATH1
);
```